# Laravel 5.7 - MustVerifyEmail abstract methods must be declared

Tags: laravel-5.7

I have the following user model:

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract,
                                    AuthorizableContract,
                                    CanResetPasswordContract,
                                    MustVerifyEmail {

   use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword, HasApiTokens, Notifiable;

  public function sendEmailVerificationNotification()
  {
    $this->notify(new VerifyEmailNotification());
  }

  //...
}
```

However I'm getting the following error:

```
 Class App\User contains 2 abstract methods and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail::hasVerifiedEmail, Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail::markEmailAsVerified)
```

Why do I need to implement these two methods. Theres nothing in the docs regarding this?

Answer (score 1):

Those methods are available in the MustVerifyEmail trait.

```
use \Illuminate\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
```

See: [Illuminate/Auth/MustVerifyEmail.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Auth/MustVerifyEmail.php)

Either add this trait and/or overload whatever you want, or add the other 2 methods and add your own business logic.